# for $X\subset \mathbb{R}$, $\mathbb{R} = int X\cup Int(\mathbb{R}-X)\cup \partial X$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

I need to prove:

for $X\subset \mathbb{R}$, $$\mathbb{R} = int X\cup Int(\mathbb{R}-X)\cup \partial X$$

The problem is that all the proofs I've found are for metric spaces, not $\mathbb{R}$ itself, which I think is a lot easier. Here's [one proof](http://math.stanford.edu/~conrad/diffgeomPage/handouts/closure.pdf) I've found. I also need to prove that this union is of disjoint sets.

My definition of interior point is the one that talks about an open ball being in the set, the definition of $\partial X$ (boundary of $X$) is the one about every neighborhood of $\mathbb{R}$ such that it contains points of $X$ and $\mathbb{R}-X$.

Any ideas on how to prove it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your definitions, this is a lot easier than the linked proof.

Let $x \in \mathbb{R}.$ Then one of three cases is possible:

(i) some open neighborhood of $x$ is contains only points in $X$

(ii) some open neighborhood of $x$ is contains only points in $\mathbb{R}-X$

(iii) none of the above

If (i) then $x \in \mathrm{int}(X)$; if (ii) then $x \in \mathrm{int}(\mathbb{R}-X)$; if (iii) then $x \in \partial X$.

This is a disjoint union because no two cases can happen at the same time.

Comment: To the OP : Note that both answers are valid for any topological space, not just for $\mathbb R.$

Answer (score 3):

Each set on the right is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$, so it is enough to show that every real number is in one of the three sets on the right.

Fix $x\in \mathbb{R}$. If $x$ is in the interior of $X$ or of $X^c$, then we are done. Otherwise $x$ is not in the interior of $X$, so every interval centered at $x$ contains points in $X^c$, and $x$ is also not in the interior of $X^c$, so every interval centered at $x$ contains points in $X$. Therefore $x\in\partial X$.